# How to change the color of GIF animated image in css

Tags: html, css, angular

I am developing angular application.I am download transparent GIF Loader image.I want to change the color of GIF image,but can't I could resize the image but unable to change the color.I searched related to this but I got only to change the background color and resize the image.Is there any way to change the color of GIF image.If canvas is the only option???

html:

```
 <div class="text-center" *ngIf="loading">
        <img src="assets/img/spinner.gif">       
      </div>
```

css:

```
img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

I want to change the color of loader not the background color.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I add background-color behind a transparent background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052846/how-can-i-add-background-color-behind-a-transparent-background-image)

Comment: That question to change the background color.I can change the backgroung color but i want to change the color of loader.

Answer (score 8):

GIF image format does not support color customisations (unlike inline SVG), so its impossible to do with/without css. You may want use try css loaders

[CSS Loaders](https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/)